# How can I update the Editor/Author field of a versioned item

Tags: development, versioning, multiline-text-field

I am using a multiline text field with `Append Changes to Existing Text` enabled. So everytime I add a new comment it creates a new version with, `Created by` set to the user who triggered the action.

I want to overwrite `Created by` a different name using server side code in C#. I tried updating `Author` and `Editor` field but that did not help.

I couldn't find a solution on the internet as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost positive that Author and Editor are read-only. They can't be updated programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

use [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/projectserver/Update-SharePoint-list-4e6272ab):

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA 0 
#specify new user - login name 
$newuser = "Support\paulmather" 
#specify the web URL 
$site = get-SPWeb http://vm353/pwa/ProjectBICenter 
#specify the list name 
$list = $site.Lists["Test"] 
$listitems = $list.Items 
$user = get-SPuser -Web $site -Identity $newuser 
#loop through each list item and update 
foreach ($listitem in $listitems) 
    { 

        $listitem["Author"] = $user 
        $listitem["Editor"] = $user        
        $listitem.Update() 
        write-host $listitem["Name"] "has been updated. The author and editor has been set to $user" 

    } 
$site.Update() 
$site.Dispose()
```

*Hope it helps!*